# Flutter awesome_notifications - Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

I am using awesome_notifications as my notification plugin; however, I get the error `"Bad state: Stream has already been listened to."` whenever I call notifInitialize() in initState(). This happens every time I hot reload the application from fresh.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    notifInitialize();
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is how I am writing my function. Is there something wrong with how I set up my listeners?

````
  void notifInitialize() {
    notificationIcon = true;
    AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
      'resource://drawable/app_icon',
      [
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          channelName: 'Basic notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
          defaultColor: Colors.teal,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          channelShowBadge: true,
        ),
        NotificationChannel(
          channelKey: 'scheduled_channel',
          channelName: 'Scheduled Notifications',
          channelDescription: 'Scheduled Description',
          defaultColor: Colors.teal,
          locked: true,
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
        ),
      ],
    );
    AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
      if (!isAllowed) {
        AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
      }
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().createdStream.listen((notification) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(
        'Notification Created on ${notification.channelKey}',
      )));
    });

    AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((notification) {
      if (notification.channelKey == 'basic_channel' && Platform.isIOS) {
        AwesomeNotifications().getGlobalBadgeCounter().then((value) {
          print(value);
          AwesomeNotifications().setGlobalBadgeCounter(value - 1);
          print(value);
        });
      }
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => ValidateService()),
          //(route) => route.isFirst);
          (route) => false);
    });
  }```
````

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some issues with your code.

- You're not disposing/cancelling the stream in your `dispose()` method
- You do not have a state to check if you have already have an existing subscription to prevent `Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.`.

For the first case, you can use the `StreamSubscription` class to save an instance of your subscription to `state` to enable you cancel it in your widget's dispose method.

```dart
StreamSubscription<ReceivedAction>? _actionStreamSubscription;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  ...

  listen();

  ...
}

void listen() async {
  // You can choose to cancel any exiting subscriptions
  await _actionStreamSubscription?.cancel();

  // assign the stream subscription
  _actionStreamSubscription = AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((message) {
    // handle stuff here
  });
}
```

```dart
@override
void dispose() async {
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
    await _actionStreamSubscription?.cancel();
  });
  super.dispose();
}
```

The above should work if you have a `dispose()` method to safely cancel existing subscriptions when the tree rebuilds.

But in a situation where you do not have a `dispose()` method, you could use a `boolean` field to determine if a subscription to the stream exists.

```dart
// somewhere in your code, assign a bool to false
bool subscribedActionStream = false;

// Just before your call to subscribe, check if not already subscribed.
if (!subscribedActionStream) {
  AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((message) {
    // handle stuff here
  });
  subscribedActionStream = true;
}
```

Whichever you decide to use should work fine.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately neither worked

Comment: I modified my answer. Extracted the stream subscription to allow use of async/await to cancel any existing subscriptions and in the `dispose` method, use Future.delayed with zero duration to cancel subscription.

Comment: Does this answer work for you?

Comment: Hi, so I opted in for another solution. I put it in my main method as a top-level function and it seems to work fine now